# Calculated column in Power BI based on relationship between 2 tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: My Data model screenshot]

Hi,

I'm trying to add a calculated column in my **MergedTable** table that will multiply the **Time** column by the sum of the indicator in the **TeamLeave** when the week ending dates and the name dates are the same but I'm not sure how or what functions to use(I've tried a number at this stage).

Could anyone provide me with assistance on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
'MergedTable'[Time] * CALCULATE(SUM('Team Leave'[Indicator]))
```

The `CALCULATE` is necessary to perform a [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) (turning the "current row" of 'MergedTable' into a filter that will propagate to the 'Team Leave' table).